# Find node value and create new node in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to modify existing XML file using XSLT. The original XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
    <object>
        <items>
            <item>
                <name>John Doe</name>    <!-- Changed tag to closing tag -->
                <public-url>http://www.johndoe.com</public-url>
            </item>
        </items>
        <records>
            <record>
                <person>
                    <field name="book">
                        <text>A book</text>
                        <links>
                            <link>http://www.acook.com</link>
                        </links>
                    </field>
                </person>
            </record>
        </records>
    </object>
</entry>
```

Now I want to use XSL to get the the user info from `<item>` and insert a new `<field>` node into `<person>`. The final result will look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
    <object>
        <items>
            <item>
                <name>John Doe<name>
                <public-url>http://www.johndoe.com</public-url>
            </item>
        </items>
        <records>
            <record>
                <person>
                    <field name="author">
                        <text>John Doe</text>
                        <links>
                            <link>http://www.johndoe.com</link>
                        </links>
                    </field>
                    <field name="book">
                        <text>A book</text>
                        <links>
                            <link>http://www.acook.com</link>
                        </links>
                    </field>
                </person>
            </record>
        </records>
    </object>
</entry>
```

Below is my attempt, I want to get the `<name>` and `<public-url>` value  from the `<item>` and become two variables. Create a new `<field>` using these two variables and insert into `<record>`. Currently I can't figure out a way to insert this new node into the correct location.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="item/">
    <xsl:variable name="username" select="@name" />
    <xsl:variable name="userurl" select="@public-url" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <field name="author">
    <text><xsl:value-of select="$username"/></text>
    <links>
         <link>
             <xsl:value-of select="$userurl" />
         </link>
    </links>
    </field>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please advices, Thank you!

Comment: How come the input has `<name>John Doe<name>` and the new field has a different name `<text>John Dow</text>`?

Comment: It was a typo. The value in <text> is from <name>

Comment: I corrected the `<name>...</name>` situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:element name="person">
        <xsl:element name="field">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:text>author</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="text">
                <xsl:value-of select="./ancestor::object/items/item/name"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="links">
                <xsl:element name="link">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./ancestor::object/items/item/public-url"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you! It refresh my memory about `ancestor`